# Including counter in the name of a variable (in for loop) [Syntax problem]

Tags: c#

So basically I'm trying to store multiple variables into an array.
These variables are all double and are named money1, money2, money3, etc.

I have a very small **syntax problem** and don't know how to phrase a search on google. The part of code I am referring to is: money[i+1].

**Is there anyway to include the actual counter in the name of the variable.**

Tried phrasing it in many ways of which none have worked.

```
    double[] answers = new double[34]
    answers[0] = userID;
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
                {
                    answers[i + 1] = money[i+1];
                }
```

Expected output of the array.

```
{userID, money1, money2, money3, mone... etc}
```

Comment: You seem to know how to use an array, so just use an array called `money`, instead of 33 variables. Then you can use the syntax you showed here.

Comment: Agree with Sweeper. If you ever find yourself writing variable names ending in numbers, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: The code you have shown will go outside the bounds of the array `answers`. The length of the array is 34 and goes from `answers[0]` to `answers[33]`. The maximum value of `i` is 33 but in the loop you try to assign to `answers[33+1]`. I know this doesn't answer your original question, but just loop from 1 and use `i` instead of `i+1`

Comment: Look into Dictionary<string, double> . It let's you acces the values by name.

Comment: one of reason, you must set  ==> for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length-1; i++)

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to _achieve_, instead of what you are trying to _do_. Plus, the question is not clear to me. Why would you want variable names, and where are these variable names coming from? What is _answers_? Why is the userID in the same array as the money? Why are you discarding the double values?

Comment: @Sweeper You're right. I got so caught up on the specific line of code that I didn't realise the inefficiency of how I was managing my variables. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else for your suggestions.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing all the `money` in `money1`, `money2`, `money3` etc, you can store them in an array, just like you did with `answers`:

```
double[] moneys = new double[33] {
    ...
};
```

And then your current code should work.

If all you want to do is just adding a `userID` at the start of the array, you can use LINQ to make your code more concise:

```
double[] answers = new double[] { userID }.Concat(moneys).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How is "money" array is implemented? maybe the problem is that his length is smaller than answers array?

For this line of code i suggest duplicate the array and than change the first element.

Something like this:

```
double[] answers = money.Clone()
answers[0] = userID;
```